# Grpc on Kotlin/JVM

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, grpc

I have been searching for long a blog or so which explains how to add grpc to my project. The best on I found was that: https://medium.com/swlh/using-grpc-with-kotlin-for-building-microservices-2a79d95a236a

Unfortunaly the steps in here are not clearly explained. Eg. where should the proto files be loctated and where should I import the Protobuf Compiler exactly (for what do I really need it?).
Error:
Execution failed for task ':stub:extractIncludeProto'.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':stub:compileProtoPath'.
   > Could not find io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/David/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-kotlin-stub/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/C:/Users/David/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-kotlin-stub/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/grpc-kotlin-stub-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-kotlin-stub/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-kotlin-stub/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/grpc-kotlin-stub-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-kotlin-stub/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-kotlin-stub/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/grpc-kotlin-stub-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
     Required by:
         project :stub

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

The base problem is probably that all [grpc tutorials](https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/kotlin/) are based on this [github repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin) and I cannot compile any project from the examples folder. The proplem there is that gradle could not find the proto-project even though it is there (in my opinion).

So I decided to ask you, if some one has a link or knowlege about how to make a simple grpc server with the base of an empty Kotlin/JVM Application.

Sorry for this simple question, but this really upsets me that this just won't work

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: If added it to my question

Comment: I really don't understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Replace `grpc-kotlin-stub` version from `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` to `1.1.0`; Beacuse snapshot can't find in those repositories. Or you should install `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT` to local maven repo first by using `mvn install` in `grpc-kotlin-stub` project.

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't solve my problem